# Method not found: class com.obs.bean.SearchBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e348f43d.getSearchBookList()

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I got this exception in `search.xhtml` page:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Method not found: class com.obs.bean.SearchBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e348f43d.getSearchBookList()
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: class com.obs.bean.SearchBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e348f43d.getSearchBookList()
```

I have a `commandButton` in `home.xhtml` page like this:

```
<h:form id="searchForm">
    <p:inputText id="srchF" value="#{searchBean.searchKeyword}"/>
    <h:commandButton styleClass="srchBtn" value="search" action="#{searchBean.search()}"/>
</h:form>
```

Here is table in `search.xhtml` page:

```
<h:dataTable id="searchTable" var="srch" value="#{searchBean.getSearchBookList()}">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Book title</f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{srch[0]}"/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And here is the `search bean`:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
@Component
public class SearchBean {

private String searchKeyword;
private List<Book> searchBookList;
@Autowired
private BookDao bookDao;

@Transactional
public String search() throws IOException {
    searchBookList = new ArrayList<Book>();
    searchBookList = bookDao.findByTitle(getSearchKeyword()).list();
    System.out.println("size of list: " + searchBookList.size()); //list size is >1
    return "search?faces-redirect=true";
}

public List<Book> getSearchBookList() {
    return searchBookList;
}

public void setSearchBookList(List<Book> searchBookList) {
    this.searchBookList = searchBookList;
}
```

Query result is exists with data.

What is wrong in this code?

**UPDATE**

I tried `value="#{searchBean.searchBookList}"` and get this error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'searchBookList' not found on type com.obs.bean.SearchBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e348f43d
```

Comment: Can't you just use value="#{searchBean.searchBookList}"

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope Then i got this `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /search.xhtml @46,83 value="#{searchBean.searchBookList}": Property 'searchBookList' not found on type com.obs.bean.SearchBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e348f43d`

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another SearchBean in your application and you are not using the wrong one ?

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope Yes, i have just one `SearchBean`.

Comment: Make sure to clean and rebuild everything to be sure you are using the last version of the source.

Comment: Won't work later on. Fix the managed bean annotations. The bean is not a session scoped JSF managed bean. It is rather a Spring singleton managed bean. It is like an application scoped bean. Those two JSF related annotations `@ManagedBean` and `@SessionScoped` are purely superfluous, since beans are managed by Spring (`@Component`) and not by JSF (`@ManagedBean`). It is as good as they are removed. You will see the exact same behaviour, event though you remove them. They are silently ignored and the default `singleton` scope associated with Spring beans will come into play in this case.